# Why ZipEntry fails to work in Jelly Bean

Tags: java, android, zip

I have a ZIP file of 140 MB containing about 40 thousand MP3 files. I use the following code to play a certain file inside the ZIP file without decompressing it:

```
String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "_audio_.mp3";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "mySoundFolder";

try {           
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(path + "myFile.zip");                     
Enumeration zipEntries = zip.entries();                          
ZipEntry entry = zip.getEntry("myFile" + "/" + currentWord + ".mp3"); 

if (entry != null) {
    Log.i(MAIN_TAG, "entry found: " + entry.getName());   
    InputStream in = zip.getInputStream(entry);  

        File f = new File(fullPath);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);     
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[4096];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
        { 
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);     
        }                       
            if (f.exists())                         
                {
                    Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Audio file found!");   
                    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                    mp.setDataSource(fullPath); 
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(null);
                    mp.setLooping(false);                   
                    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
                    { public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) 
                        { 
                            mp.start();                         
                        Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"Pronunciation finished!");
                        }});                                            

                        }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"File doesn't exist!!"); 
                    }                       
                } 
                else {
                    // no such entry in the zip
                    Log.i(MAIN_TAG, "no such entry in the zip");                
                 }              
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
             Log.i(MAIN_TAG,"IOException reading zip file");                
            }           
        }
```

There are two strange things with this code:

1. It works flawlessly in `Android 2.2` but fails in `Android 4.0.3`. In `2.2`, it finds and plays the MP3 file as I expect, but in `4.0.3`, it keeps saying it cannot find the entry in the ZIP file (`"no such entry in the zip"`).
2. If I reduce the number of MP3 files down to about 100 files, then in `Android 4.0.3`, it finds and plays the selected MP3 files as it should do.

Can you guys please help me to figure out what the problem is?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Does this code work fine on a non-android environment (ex:PC)? i.e, does `zip.getEntry("myFile" + "/" + currentWord + ".mp3");` return an entry instead of null on a PC?

Comment: I have no idea because I have no chance to test that way. But note this problem occurs only in `Android 4x` and with the zip file of more than 40k entries.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I have a workaround for this problem. I split my zip file into two files, with each containing about `20k entries`. Voila, it works like a charm again.

I've heard of Java's problem with reading entries in zip files of more than `64k entries`. What I have no idea why is my file has only about 40k entries but it faces the problem as well.